# chrome: 30px looks different on localhost vs heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, heroku

I'm not sure what to look at to correct this.

I have a Rails app, where I'm precompiling my assets with rake assets:precompile before deploying to Heroku.

Then when I view my app online in Chrome, the 30px font-size I'm using looks a lot smaller live than on my localhost. Inspecting the element still shows that it's at 30px though. And everything displays well in Firefox and Safari.

What should I look at? thanks in advance!

Comment: all of your `css` is compiled into `application.css` in production (or staging) . My bet is that somewhere in your code, the `30px` font rule gets overwritten. Try to see what other rules are inherited.

Comment: well, if it were overwritten, then when i'd go into developer tools and inspect my element, i wouldn't see it being 30px. But, that's my case, in dev tools, in production, the size is 30px. Just that the 30px on my localhost, vs the 30px when i push to heroku differ. But now I just tested on other machines and it displays well. So it's something i messed up in my Chrome settings on my main machine. But even when I reset my Chrome settings, I still get this issue...

Comment: what about other browsers?

Comment: well exactly, in other browsers, everything is fine. It's just in Chrome. I wouldn't say it's a solution, but I ended up creating a new user profile in my Chrome to get to see everything display in the right way... A reset was not enough... I don't know what made this happen though... It's not really a solution because I don't want to loose all my settings.. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Have you tried 'More Tools > Clear Browser Data'?

Comment: yes, i cleared browser data multiple times..